# How to shuffle an array

Tags: java, playing-cards

I have an question about how to shuffle an array. The **background** is:
Write a memory matching game, which using 16 cards that laid out in a 4*4 square and are labeled with pairs of number from 1 to 8.

**Currently, what I need to do is to initialize these cards and shuffle these cards.**

And now what I can think of is that creating a Card class including variable Rank from 1 to 8, secondly, naming a new class (matchingGame)(whatever you like) and writing a new static method: shuffle().

But I am stuck at this step.

**My first question** is how to initialize these 16 cards (8 pairs)?
(I think my code is not the efficient way).

**My second question** is how to shuffle cards after initialization?

My code is:

```
public class Card 
{
private int rank;

public Card(int iniRank)
{
    switch (iniRank)
    {
    case 1:
        rank =1;
        break;
    case 2:
        rank =2;
        break;
    case 3:
        rank =3;
        break;
    case 4:
        rank =4;
        break;
    case 5:
        rank =5;
        break;
    case 6:
        rank =6;
        break;
    case 7:
        rank =7;
        break;
    case 8:
        rank =8;
        break;
    }
}

public int getRank()
{
    return rank;
}


}


public static void initialize(Card[] cards)
{
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        cards[i] = new Card(1);
    }
    for (int i=2;i<4;i++)
    {
        cards[i] = new Card(2);
    }
....
}
```

Thanks everyone for my previous question!
Just one more question in the same background, As your good advice, you know how to shuffle a 1D array?

**But how to shuffle a 2D array?** Obviously, I cannot use

```
List<Card> newcards = Arrays.asList(cards)
```

for converting to List now.

Thanks for ur help

Comment: There's no need to use a _switch statement_.  You can just set rank to the value of _iniRank_.  To figure out how to shuffle, you'll want to look at how to create random numbers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method for initializing the array is essentially correct: loop through your array and add a new instance at each point.

```
Card[] cards = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
    cards[i] = ...  // new Card instance
```

Now for shuffling - don't reinvent the wheel: Use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29):

```
Card[] cards = ...;
List<Card> l = Arrays.asList(cards);
Collections.shuffle(l);
```

Comment: @A. R. S. do you mean that creating an arraylist and using collections.shuffle?  and how to shuffle an array? could you help me with that?

Comment: @Ivy - He already answered that question above: convert the array to a collection, shuffle it, then convert it back to an array.

Comment: @Ivy `Collections.shuffle` takes a `List` (not an array). So in the code I posted we first convert the array to a `List`, call `Collections.shuffle` on it, and then convert this shuffled list back into an array and restore it in the original variable, as jahroy indicated.

Comment: you don't need the last `toArray()` call because the `asList()` wrapper will write-through to the array.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a `switch` statement in your constructor, as I think you've realized. Just assign `rank` the value of the int parameter directly.

I'm also not sure what's going on in your initialization method. You create a loop that iterates twice, to create a card of a certain rank?

As far as shuffling goes, you may want to look at the [Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle).

Comment: You beat me to it on the Knuth shuffle!

Comment: Sorry -- I have to give credit to www.codinghorror.com for first putting it in my brain! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you think of the card positions linearly (ie as a single list of grid positions left to right, top to bottom), you can simply use the [`shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method of the Collections utility class:

```
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
// populate the list with what ever cards you want, how you want
Collections.shuffle(cards);
```

then display the cards as a grid

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend implementing [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm.

It is efficient, well known, and correct. You'd be surprised how important the latter is - [see this for an interesting example](http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php) of what can happen when a casino implements an incorrect shuffle algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your switch statement. You could just create a Card class like this:

```
public class Card 
{
   private int rank;

   public Card(int iniRank){
      rank = iniRank;
   }

   public int getRank(){
      return rank;
   }
}
```

Than you create the matchingGame class. Add 16 Cards then shuffle them.

```
public class matchingGame
{
   private List<Card> cards = null;

   public matchingGame(){
      cards = new ArrayList<Card>(16);
      for (int i=1; i<=8; i++)
      {
         cards.add(new Card(i));
         cards.add(new Card(i));
      }
   }

   public void shuffle()
   {
      //Shuffle algorithm here.
   }
}
```

For the algorithm I would suggest to look at this post: [Java's Collections.shuffle is doing what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249520/javas-collections-shuffle-is-doing-what)