# how to get random item from an arraylist without any repeatation in android

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList` of an object from where I want items of a particular position, but everytime I launch the Activity the retrieved position should be randomize and also won't repeat until every position Item is completely retrieved. I used this method:

```
public static int getRandomNumber(ArrayList<Integer> arr)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            Random random = new Random();
            int select = random.nextInt(arr.size());
            int randomnum = arr.get(select);
            GlobalData.randList.remove(select);
            return randomnum;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

                GlobalData.randList.add(i);

            }
            return 0;
        }
```

but its not working,like duplicate number is coming, there may be a reason because everytime I am re launching the activity. I did it in `oncreate` instead of `onResume` but its not working as I expected? Is there any other way to work with it? Any solution?

Comment: Use Collections.shuffle

Comment: Can U explain a bit? will it not be repeated until it finishes every position?

Comment: The comment is short because I have given this answer many times in the last few weeks alone. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Collections.shuffle()` to shuffle the array.  Use another variable to track the current position in the array.  Each time you retrieve a new value increment the variable. Once you reach the end of the array re-shuffle it.

Reference:
[Shuffling algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_algorithms)

```
public class RandomArray {
    ArrayList<Integer> array = null;
    int position = 0;

    public RandomArray(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        array = arr;
        position = arr.size();
    }

    public int getNext() {
        if (position == array.size()) {
           position = 0;
           Collections.shuffle(array);
        }
        return array.get(position++);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your system, but it repeats :(

Comment: Yes, it repeats after each element in the array has been display once. It will also repeat if you have duplicates in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the original order, you can try this:

```
Object[] array = new Object[10];    // say 10 objects
int remain = array.length;
Random rnd = new Random();

public Object next () {
    if (remain == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        int i = rnd.nextInt(remain--);
        Object tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[remain];
        array[remain] = tmp;
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

You can also do similar thing with ArrayList.

Well, in this way, it is faster than shuffle() method. [shuffle()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249520/javas-collections-shuffle-is-doing-what) has the time complexity of O(n) while my code is O(1).

Comment: after getting one object I am changing the activity, how can I continue if I come back in this activity again?

Comment: You can write the randomizing code in a separate class and make the method static.