# Select multiple/random elements from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, random

How would I select random elements from an array list, except for **one** element?
Here's my arraylist:

```
ArrayList <String> provinces = new ArrayList();

Collections.addAll(
    provinces, 
    "New Brunswick", 
    "Saskatchewan", 
    "Ontario", 
    "Nova Scotia", 
    "Quebec", 
    "Alberta");
```

For this example, I would like to select at random the other elements, **except for** Saskatchewan.

I've tried doing:

```
 for(int i == provinces.get (0); i < provinces.get(1); i > provinces.get(2); i < provinces.get(5)) {

     int getPossibleAnswers = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*i);               
     String displayPossibleAnswers = provinces.get(getPossibleAnswers);                
     outputAnswers.append(displayPossibleAnswers + "\n");
     }
```

Obviously, this code doesn't work, and I don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: but how many elements do you need?

Comment: why don't you simply create a list without `Saskatchewan` and apply `Collections.shuffle` on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a list of all the index values, except for the index to Saskatchewan, then shuffle that.

```
List<String> provinces = Arrays.asList("New Brunswick", "Saskatchewan", "Ontario", "Nova Scotia", "Quebec", "Alberta");

List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < provinces.size(); i++)
    if (! provinces.get(i).equals("Saskatchewan"))
        indexes.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(indexes);

StringBuilder outputAnswers = new StringBuilder();
for (int i : indexes)
    outputAnswers.append(provinces.get(i) + "\n");

System.out.print(outputAnswers);
```

*Sample Output*

```
Nova Scotia
Quebec
Ontario
Alberta
New Brunswick
```

Comment: Sorry, sort of new to Java, what does the colon (:) do?

Comment: @PendleS That is the enhanced `for` loop, also known as the foreach loop. See: [What is the syntax of enhanced for loop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11685305/5221149)

Comment: Thanks you for the answers

Answer (score 1):

To keep it concise , As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441703/select-multiple-random-elements-from-an-arraylist/44442236#comment75881328_44441703) Simply create a `list` without `Saskatchewan`

```
    ArrayList <String> provinces = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("New Brunswick",
                                     "Ontario", "Nova Scotia",
                                     "Quebec",   "Alberta"));
```

then shuffle the `list`

```
Collections.shuffle(provinces);
```

Demo

```
ArrayList <String> provinces = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("New Brunswick",
                                     "Ontario", "Nova Scotia",
                                     "Quebec",   "Alberta"));
Collections.shuffle(provinces);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s:provinces) {
    builder.append(s+"\n");
}
System.out.println(builder);
```

Output :

```
Quebec
New Brunswick
Alberta
Ontario
Nova Scotia
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList <String> provinces = new ArrayList<>();
String removeValue = null;
Collections.addAll(
    provinces, 
    "New Brunswick", 
    "Saskatchewan", 
    "Ontario", 
    "Nova Scotia", 
    "Quebec", 
    "Alberta");

for (Iterator<String> iterator = provinces.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    String value = iterator.next();
    if (value.equals("Saskatchewan")) {
        removeValue = value;
        iterator.remove();
    }
}

Collections.shuffle(provinces);

for(String p: provinces){
    System.out.println(p);
}

provinces.add(removeValue);
```

I used [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) because enhanced `for` loop did not work with `remove()` but without [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) you can also loop using indexes(numbers).

Without [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
for (int j = 0; j<provinces.size(); j++) {
    if(provinces.get(j).equals("Saskatchewan")){
        removeValue = provinces.get(j);
        provinces.remove(provinces.get(j));
    }
}
```

Also without using [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249520/javas-collections-shuffle-is-doing-what) you can create your own method. To do that have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

If you need randomization often (e.g. for randomized testing), you can add a [Qala Datagen](https://github.com/qala-io/datagen) dependency and then get a random element like this:

```
String e = sample(provinces);
```

Though you'd still need to remove extra element from the collection.

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of the lib.